# Resource limit exceeded in druid groupBy Query

Tags: druid

I am trying to run groupBy Query above the limit of 500k data. I am getting this error.

```
{
    "error": "Resource limit exceeded",
    "errorMessage": "Not enough dictionary space to execute this query. Try increasing druid.query.groupBy.maxMergingDictionarySize or enable disk spilling by setting druid.query.groupBy.maxOnDiskStorage to a positive number.",
    "errorClass": "io.druid.query.ResourceLimitExceededException",
    "host": "ubuntu:8083"
}
```

How can i use groupBy Query above the limit of 500k data? I am using druid 0.11.0 version and groupBy v2 engine. I have 1 million row data that i am running query on it.

I have tried increasing the `druid.query.groupBy.maxMergingDictionarySize` and `druid.query.groupBy.maxOnDiskStorage` but this does not solve my problem.

**EDIT**

When i tried increasing `druid.processing.buffer.sizeBytes` this error occurs in linux terminal.

```
5 errors
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1028) ~[guice-4.1.0.jar:?]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1050) ~[guice-4.1.0.jar:?]
        at io.druid.guice.LifecycleModule$2.start(LifecycleModule.java:154) ~[druid-api-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
        at io.druid.cli.GuiceRunnable.initLifecycle(GuiceRunnable.java:101) [druid-services-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
        at io.druid.cli.ServerRunnable.run(ServerRunnable.java:50) [druid-services-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
        at io.druid.cli.Main.main(Main.java:108) [druid-services-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
```

Comment: There must be more errors in the log files of druid

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to increase the buffer sizes on all historical and realtime nodes and broker nodes.

```
druid.processing.buffer.sizeBytes
```

Also increase the `druid.query.groupBy.maxMergingDictionarySize` and `druid.query.groupBy.maxOnDiskStorage`

And double check that your machines are not running out of disk.

Comment: when i increase maxOnDiskStorage and when i run query on postman it crashes.

Comment: What is your Druid version ?

Comment: version that i am using is 0.11.0

Comment: Can you see the druid logs and see whats there after increasing the above mentioned sizes.

Comment: Where do i have to change the configuration in conf-quickstart or conf ??? I am still confused about this

Comment: If you are running druid in cluster mode than it should be in conf, if in single machine mode than in conf-quickstart.

Comment: i got to run the query but its too slow. Suggest any performance tuning

Comment: share your query and configuration and data details, may be than I can help. You can check some benchmark here - http://druid.io/blog/2014/03/17/benchmarking-druid.html

Comment: sorry my bad i was using postman to get response directly, when i saved the response to a file then its speed is good. thanks for your valuable time